# Does MongoDB support floating point types?

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I am migrating a mysql database to mongodb. But i have read in MongoDb data types and then there is no reference to floating point types like, float, double, decimal.

And how i have some fields with decimal types in my sql schema , how can i do or what can i do?

Comment: [Mongo 3.4 adds support for decimal datatype](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40986686/1090562)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

MongoDB stores data in a binary format called [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification) which supports these numeric data types:

- `int32` - 4 bytes (32-bit signed integer)
- `int64` - 8 bytes (64-bit signed integer)
- `double` - 8 bytes (64-bit IEEE 754 floating point)

There's no exact value fixed-point equivalent to mySQL's `decimal` type in MongoDB, but you can store 64-bit floating point numbers in Mongo as a `double`.

It's worth mentioning that the MongoDB shell - being a JavaScript shell - doesn't recognise the distinction between integer and floating-point values, it treats all numbers the same because JavaScript represents all numbers as 64-bit floating point, regardless of their underlying BSON type.

Most [MongoDB language drivers](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Drivers), however, make the distinction between integer and floating point types.

Comment: The fact that it is IEEE 754 floating point is very important to people who value reproducible computing.  Surprisingly even [Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-79FEJH/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-79FEJH) does not support this!

Comment: @meawoppl Matlab most definitely supports IEEE 754.

Answer (score 11):

Chris already provided information about floating point types, so I will just add information about [Decimal data type](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/release-notes/3.4/#decimal-type) that was added in Mongo 3.4

> 3.4 adds support for the decimal128 format with the new decimal data type. The decimal128 format supports numbers with up to 34 decimal
>   digits (i.e. significant digits) and an exponent range of −6143 to
>   +6144.
>
> Unlike the double data type, which only stores an approximation of the
>   decimal values, the decimal data type stores the exact value. For
>   example, a decimal NumberDecimal("9.99") has a precise value of 9.99
>   where as a double 9.99 would have an approximate value of
>   9.9900000000000002131628...

Answer (score 1):

It has, [Introduction](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Introduction)

> A value is a
>
> - basic type like string, integer, **float**, timestamp, binary, etc.,
> - a document, or
> - an array of values

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB does support storing doubles, but not all drivers provide an interface to them for some reason.

From http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Data+Types+and+Conventions -

> Mongo uses special data types in addition to the basic JSON types of string, integer, boolean, **double**, null, array, and object.