# Storing Time Stamp as Number Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I'm new to Mongoid. In my model file, I've created a field with data type BigDecimal. I want to store time stamp in it. Below is the model that I'm using:

```
class Test
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :time_stamp, type: BigDecimal
end
```

And Below is the code that I'm using to create a document:

```
aTime = "Wed Apr 24 09:48:38 +0000 2013"
timest = aTime.to_time.to_i
Test.create({time_stamp: timest})
```

I see that the time_stamp is stored as String in the database. Can anybody direct me to store the timestamp as number in DB so that I could perform some operations on it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To store timestamps, you need to `include Mongoid::Timestamps` .. This will create :created_at & :updated_at fields to your document. Not sure how your field `:time_stamp` is magically populated with a time string.

Comment: This might be a bug in Mongoid's MongoDB driver, Moped. Can you post the data that you can see by querying in the mongo shell?

If you really just want to store the timestamp, you can just set the field type to `Time` instead of `BigDecimal`.

Comment: @senthil, just tried to reproduce and turned up the value(time_stamp) was stored as a number. mongoid (3.0.23)

Comment: What's wrong with using field :time_stamp, type: DateTime? You get proper date/time and supports timezones as well.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7682922/619510), the numeric types supported by MongoDB are:

```
MongoDB stores data in a binary format called BSON which supports these numeric data types:

int32 - 4 bytes (32-bit signed integer)
int64 - 8 bytes (64-bit signed integer)
double - 8 bytes (64-bit IEEE 754 floating point)
```

Reinforced by this statement in the [Mongoid documentation](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html#fields):

```
Types that are not supported as dynamic attributes since they cannot be cast are:

BigDecimal
Date
DateTime
Range
```

I don't know about the things you want to with the field, but if you really want it stored as a number, you have to use a different numeric type that is supported by the MongoDB (BSON), probably `Float` or `Integer`.

Comment: This is not relevant because `field :time_stamp, type: BigDecimal` does specify a supported field type, BigDecimal. It ought to be converting it to an integer before storing on MongoDB.

Comment: I would think that **double** makes more sense than **int32** for a **decimal**, yet not enough for a **unbounded decimal** (therefore it must be stored as something else, like a **string**). If your field can be represented as a MongoDB **int32** or MongoDB **int64**, then make it a Mongoid **Integer**, not Mongoid **BigDecimal**.