# Mongoid puts float values on fields when string is given

Tags: validation, mongoid

I am using Ruby 1.9.3-p448 and Rails 3.2.13. I have this simple model with a float format validation:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :height, type: Float
  field :weight, type: Float

  validates :height, presence: true, format: { with: /[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+/ }
  validates :weight, presence: true, format: { with: /[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+/ }

end
```

If i run this code:

```
test = User.new(height:"hi", weight:"try")
```

It gives me the following result:

```
#<User _id: 51f67b49781018056b000008, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, height: 0.0,width: 0.0>
```

Why does mongoid put a 0.0 value if I put a string? I was expecting a validation error.

Comment: What error do you expect?

Comment: i am expecting a format validation error

Comment: also when i run User.validators on console it prints 

[#<Mongoid::Validations::PresenceValidator:0xa7e51d0 @attributes=[:height], @options={}>, #
<Mongoid::Validations::PresenceValidator:0xa7e38d0 @attributes=[:weight], @options={}>, #<Mongoid::Validations::PresenceValidator:0xa907824 @attributes=[:chest], @options={}>]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get no validation error because the method `new` doesn't trigger the validation, to see it you should execute:

```
User.create!(height:"hi", weight:"try")
# .../mongoid-3.1.0/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:335:in `fail_validate!': (Mongoid::Errors::Validations)
# Problem:
#   Validation of User failed.
# Summary:
#   The following errors were found: Height is invalid, Weight is invalid
# ...
```

Given that, the fields `height` and `weight` are filled with `0.0` because the `String`s are converted to `Float` using the `to_f` method, that behaves like this:

```
'foo'.to_f
# => 0.0
```

Moreover, it is useless to validate a floating point field using a regular expression because the conversion to `Float` is performed before the validation, so the validation always fails because of the behaviour of `=~`:

```
1.2 =~ /any_regexp/
# => nil
```

**Update** To validates that, given as string, the field is a valid number you can use the `numericality` option:

```
class User
  # ...
  validates :height, presence: true, numericality: true
  # ...
end

User.create!(height: '0.0')
# => #<User ... >

User.create!(height: 'foo')
# Problem:
#  Validation of User failed.
# ...
```

Comment: Thats exactly my problem thank you!
So i must check the format in client side or cani do it in server side by another way?

Answer (score -1):

MongoDB stores data in a binary format called BSON which supports these numeric data types:

- `int32` - 4 bytes (32-bit signed integer)
- `int64` - 8 bytes (64-bit signed integer)
- `double` - 8 bytes (64-bit IEEE 754 floating point)

There's no exact value fixed-point equivalent to mySQL's decimal type in MongoDB, but you can store 64-bit floating point numbers in Mongo as a double.

It's worth mentioning that the MongoDB shell - being a JavaScript shell - doesn't recognise the distinction between integer and floating-point values, it treats all numbers the same because JavaScript represents all numbers as 64-bit floating point, regardless of their underlying BSON type.

Most [MongoDB language drivers](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/), however, make the distinction between integer and floating point types.

From -> [Does MongoDB support floating point types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682714/does-mongodb-support-floating-point-types/7682922#7682922)

Comment: i am using mongoid and i cant specity Double as data type i have only Flaot
http://two.mongoid.org/docs/documents/fields.html

Comment: Downvoted, because it's an exact copy of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7682922/1087866). If the answer should have been the same then just link to the other question.