# How to make it decimal (1.25, 1.65 etc) (php)

Tags: php, mongodb, decimal

I'm using MongoDB as a database.
And I've made some record just like "1.65" "1.25" "1.95" etc.

But it defines them as a string.

When I record them like `$a = (int) $value` It drops after '.' and record it as "1" "1" "1"...

How can I transform it to decimal values?

I need to sum up all values and I should transform them to decimal to do this.

Comment: What is the field statement? and you should use intfloat for conversion

Comment: MongoDB supports double http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682714/does-mongodb-support-floating-point-types

Comment: Are you really expecting a float string like "1.65" to be converted to an int and keep the decimal part ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you cast a value to an integer its is no decimal number, decimal numbers are of type double. So cast it to double should work.

```
$a = (double) $value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo number_format($value,2,'.','');?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Integer` values are not using `.`, these are `double or float` values, try

```
$a = (double) $value;// or $a = (float) $value;
```

After addition you should use [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) for formatting.