# Methods for storing small integers in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to optimize DB size for a collection that contains a lot of documents.  The documents have a number of properties that are represented by small integers (< 255).  In the SQL Server world these would be stored as tinyint values, but the smallest BSON type I can find is Int32.

Are there an alternatives for efficiently storing small integers in MongoDB?

Answer (score 3):

`Tinyint` data type is equal by `Byte` (-256 < Byte < 255) and `SmallInt` by `Int16`.

But **MongoDB** stores data in a binary format called BSON which supports these numeric data types:

- int32 - 4 bytes (32-bit signed integer)
- int64 - 8 bytes (64-bit signed integer)
- double - 8 bytes (64-bit IEEE 754 floating point)

Reference:

[Does MongoDB support floating point types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682714/does-mongodb-support-floating-point-types)

[BSON Types](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/)