# How to store float value in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, laravel

I'm using `jenssegers/laravel-mongodb` package (for Laravel) and I'm trying to store float values in database so I can order them but it always stores them as string. I tried using `$casts` attribute and I tried direct casting like `$some_value = (float)$value;` but it doesn't work.

Is it possible to cast the attribute while calling orderBy function, in other words, is it possible to trick Eloquent so it orders the rows as float, not as string (I attempted to fix this with mutators but still no progress).

EDIT:

This is the mutator that I use. It works ok for "int" part, but when it's float then the `rate` is converted to string.
I tried converting everything to float but it didn't help

```
public function setRateAttribute($value)
{
    if(strpos($value, ".") !== false or is_float($value)) {
        $this->attributes['rate'] = (float)$value;
    } else {
        $this->attributes['rate'] = (int)$value;
    }
}
```

EDIT2:

```
$c = new \App\Contractor();
$c->rate = "1.5";
$c->save();
```

This is example from `php artisan tinker`, it's the same in application only with additional fields. 
The problem is that some entries are converted to `float` but some are `string`. I can't reproduce it always, it happens randomly.

This is example response when I loop through all entries and `var_dump` only rate:

```
string(5) "16.67"
string(5) "33.33"
string(5) "24.44"
string(5) "33.33"
string(5) "33.33"
string(5) "27.78"
string(5) "27.78"
string(4) "8.89"
string(4) "6.67"
string(5) "22.22"
string(5) "16.67"
int(0)
float(1.5)
float(1.5)
```

Comment: You will need to post some code that helps people to reproduce your issue. Without that you shouldn't expect any helpful responses here.

Comment: @dnickless It's updated

Comment: How do you store that object? And what's the result? Can you give an example, please?

Comment: @dnickless It's updated, thanks for your interest in helping me

Comment: If you added the mutator after you already had existing data in the DB, the values won't change until you set the attribute again and save each entity. `$casts` seems to be broken with that package. There are several open issues about it.

Comment: @CyRossignol You are right, but I tried to fix saved data in foreach loop and updating it like this: $c->rate = $c->rate;$c->save(); but it didn't work. This example should call the mutator and fix the values.

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682714/does-mongodb-support-floating-point-types

Answer (score -1):

MongoDB doesn't support float directly; it has double instead, so you can use 
$some_value = (double)$value;

and you need to make sure the syntax is correct.

Comment: In PHP float and double are the same thing